# getComputedStyle width issue (with span element as child)

Tags: javascript, css

I' using electron.js + bootstap and I have a button and is trying to get the actual with of it.

```
<button id="button" class="btn btn-danger" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; resize: none;">
BUTTON1
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-music"></span>
</button>
```

As you can see the width of the button element shown in the chrome debugger is "104.312px".

But the value I get from:

```
var buttonStyle = window.getComputedStyle(my_button_element, null);
alert(buttonStyle.width);
```

is "100.438px".

And if I remove the span icon leaving only the button element then the value from chrome debugger and my code is the same.

[image]
Any advice is appreciated, thanks :)

Update:

Here is a [jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/supersuraccoon/jv9r3Lh6/1/)

```
var div = document.getElementById("div");

// add a button
var button = document.createElement("button");
button.innerHTML = "BUTTON";
div.appendChild(button);
console.log("width 1: " + getComputedStyle(button).width);

button.onclick = function() {
    console.log("width onclick: " + getComputedStyle(button).width);
};

// add a span : bootstrap icon
var span = document.createElement("span");
span.className = "glyphicon glyphicon-music";
button.appendChild(span);

console.log("width 2: " + getComputedStyle(button).width);

// delay
setTimeout(function() {
    console.log("width 3: " + getComputedStyle(button).width);
}, 3000);
```

The output is :

```
width 1: 72.5312px
width 2: 82.6562px            <======   what I want is 86.5312px
width 3: 86.5312px
width onclick 3: 86.5312px
width onclick 3: 86.5312px
width onclick 3: 86.5312px
```

I tried some methond on "force DOM to update" :

```
button.style.display = 'none';
button.style.display = 'block';
```

or using jquery

```
$(button).hide().show(0);
```

But it still did not work .....

Update:

I tried to remove the button and leaving only the span element and I found that I still can not get the right value of width.

So it might be a problem with getting the with of span element using getComputedStyle.

```
var div = document.getElementById("div");

var span = document.createElement("span");
span.className = "glyphicon glyphicon-music";
div.appendChild(span);

console.log("width 1: " + getComputedStyle(span).width);

setTimeout(function() {
    console.log("width 2: " + getComputedStyle(span).width);
}, 3000);
```

And the output is:

```
width 1: 10.125px
width 2: 14px
```

Comment: is there by any chance a 2px border on the button?

Comment: I think not. I've added a demo on jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/supersuraccoon/jv9r3Lh6/1/   maybe you can have a look, thanks :)

Comment: It seems the problem is that just after inserting the element, Chrome hasn't rendered the icon yet. You can see this by using an alert instead of console.log. I'm not sure there is a better solution than setTimeout.

Comment: I also thought that is the problem so I tried some "force DOM update" method I found on this site (but neither works).  You can see the updated info.